# How to render sprites alised (sharp) in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, pixel-art

Is there a way to disable Anti-Alising in cycles so renders will be pixelated?
In Workbench there is option for no filtering but its missing from Cycles.

[image: Cycles render]

[image: Workbench render]

Answer (score 2):

so i went from [image: BH 1.5px] to [image: BH 0.01px] by going Render Properties->Film->Pixel Filter->Width and setting as low as it would go (0.01px instead of 1.5px)

you'll probably also want to make sure Render Properties->Motion Blur and (with camera selected) Object Data Properties->Depth of Field are disabled

[image: Render Properties][image: Object Data Properties]

Answer (score 0):

In the compositor workspace you can scale the image down, use a *Pixelate* node and scale back to original size.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/pixelate.html